# DirectX Toolkit C++ SpriteBatch Draw Rectangle

Tags: c++, directx, toolkit, spritebatch

I am using DirectX 11, DirectX Toolkit and C++. How can I create a rectangle with a blue border for spritebatch ? I'm guessing I need to create a texture in memory perhaps with a 1 pixel blue border ?

```
ComPtr<ID3D11ShaderResourceView>    spriteSheet_;

ComPtr<ID3D11Resource> resource;
    CreateDDSTextureFromFile(d3dDevice_, L"mytex.dds", resource.GetAddressOf(),
        spriteSheet_.ReleaseAndGetAddressOf());

batch->Draw(spriteSheet_.Get(), position, &sourceRect, DirectX::Colors::White,
        rotation_, spriteOrigin_, scale_, DirectX::SpriteEffects_None, depth_);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SpriteBatch` to draw a single-pixel texture as you described--you could use a white texture and use the SpriteBatch tinting to make it Blue.

Here is some simple code for programmatically creating a 1x1 white texture in Direct3D 11:

```
    Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11ShaderResourceView> pWhiteTexture;

    static const uint32_t s_pixel = 0xffffffff;

    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA initData = { &s_pixel, sizeof(uint32_t), 0 };

    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC desc;
    memset( &desc, 0, sizeof(desc) );
    desc.Width = desc.Height = desc.MipLevels = desc.ArraySize = 1;
    desc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    desc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_IMMUTABLE;
    desc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;

    Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> tex;
    HRESULT hr = mDevice->CreateTexture2D( &desc, &initData, &tex );

    DX::ThrowIfFailed(hr);

    D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC SRVDesc;
    memset( &SRVDesc, 0, sizeof( SRVDesc ) );
    SRVDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    SRVDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
    SRVDesc.Texture2D.MipLevels = 1;

    hr = mDevice->CreateShaderResourceView( tex.Get(), &SRVDesc, &pWhiteTexture );

    DX::ThrowIfFailed(hr);
```

A more efficient solution would be to use `PrimitiveBatch` to draw a blue quad where you want it located.

See the DirectX Tool Kit tutorial [Simple rendering](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Simple-rendering)

Comment: Yeah thats what I am using now, I made a small texture and coloured it, Its not ideal as it isnt bordered, using a quad was my next option but it seems overkill for screen based sprites.
XNA examples have answers where they use Texture2D to create a 1,1pixel texture in memory but I cant seem to get it working using c++'s id3d11texture2d and its _desc !